# practical use of lazy sequences

Tags: clojure

Usually the sequence operations I perform, I always realzie them using a `doall`. Thus I am wondering what is the practical use of having lazy sequences ?

All examples I have seen online where lazy sequences are used are for seq building - (take 5 (range)) - this code could have been rewritten as - (range 5) too - my point being is that all seq generation can be done even without lazy seq, so what is their practical need ?

I have only seen examples of lazy seq for generating numeric seqs, is there any other application ?

Comment: see https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/lazy-seq

Comment: I can recommend reading the chapter on streams in SICP at https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-24.html#%_sec_3.5

Comment: I normally use `(vec ...)` to force non-laziness.  Also `mapv` and my own macro `forv`. I use laziness only 1% of the time (for very large sequences). It should not be the default IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

They produce their results on-demand and can stop producing whenever necessary.
That enables things like infinite seqs, parallelization of processing, combining operations and avoiding temporary storage (which can be further optimized by using transducers)

Lastly laziness makes it easy to turn recursive algorithms into sequences (using `lazy-seq`)

Comment: 1) Can you elaborate more with on parellelization of processing, how is that achieved by the usage of lazy seqs ?

2) Could you give an example of combining operations and avoiding temporary storage ?

Comment: You could look at the source code for `pmap` which parallelizes a map operation on lazy sequences. It is trivial to implement. 
A good description of some of the benefits of laziness: http://clojure-doc.org/articles/language/laziness.html#benefits-of-lazy-sequences

As well as transducers: https://clojure.org/guides/faq#transducers_vs_seqs

Answer (score 2):

One of the lazy seq examples (although I'm not sure if it's a great one) can be found in the [tentacles library](https://github.com/Raynes/tentacles/blob/0e16d9f04777efd7c56b6306b9ea7d850c0a8d0d/src/tentacles/core.clj#L130).

Eric Normand also shows an example of [reading pages of data from a database](https://purelyfunctional.tv/lesson/the-benefits-of-laziness/) while leveraging lazy sequences so the client only fetches pages which they really need.

As a side note: the Programming Clojure book (3rd ed., p. 85) mentions the following guidelines for using lazy sequences:

- Be lazy when producing large or variable-sized sequences.
- Don't realize more of a lazy seq than you need
- Use recursion [i.e. eager evaluation] when producing scalar values or small, fixed sequences.